# Google Script Sheets API - default number format

Tags: google-sheets-api

It looks like google sheets is making the same mistake as Excel, by "thinking ahead" and converting the value "1.1.1" to 2001.01.01 when doing `sheet.appendRow`. I have tried to set the number format of the column in charge to "@" (which should be plain text) before inserting rows - but looks ineffective.  On the other hand doing the same after inserts is also ineffective, as the content is already "date".
Adding ' before is working, but it is not what I need.

Is there any way to give a default format or to disable such automatic conversion (from google script)?

Comment: Well, at least range.setValue works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a cell in which a form deposits a variable number of values seperated by a comma such as: " 1, 2, 4, 6 " etc - when there are only three answers, Google "helps" me by converting the value into a date object. But it's supposed to be a list of choices...

It's not pretty, but I've managed a workaround by using *.getDisplayValue* instead of *.getValue* - it does change the cell value into a string, so if you need to do further manipulations that are dependent on the value being a number or something, obviously, this fails.

I overwrite the value for the problem cell in my array before passing it to *.appendRow*

```
//getting the values
var values = s.getRange(row,1,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
//brute force crushing of problem value
values[5] = s.getRange(row,6).getDisplayValue();
```